# Extract PDF File from DB server and show file into apex application

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, database-server

How can I retrieve pdf files from DB server to my Oracle application.
I have create directory in DB server and upload 2 pdf files there now I have to show these files into my oracle apex interactive report

Answer (score 1):

This helped me a lot. Here is an example to display BLOB contents (PDF, Images) into a region in Oracle Apex page.

https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/08/display-blob-contents-pdf-images-into-a-region-in-oracle-apex-page.html